# Symfony project deployment on apache server - cache rename file error

Tags: windows, apache, symfony, filesystems

I was trying to deploy my first symfony project to an appache server running on windows. Sometimes the request fail and I get this following error:

**Cannot rename "C:\xampp\htdocs\qradmin\var\dev\cache\urlAF58.tmp" to "C:\xampp\htdocs\qradmin\var\dev\cache/url_matching_routes.php".**

I have not changed any cache settings - here is the config/packages/cache.yaml

```
framework:
    cache:
        # Unique name of your app: used to compute stable namespaces for cache keys.
        #prefix_seed: your_vendor_name/app_name

        # The "app" cache stores to the filesystem by default.
        # The data in this cache should persist between deploys.
        # Other options include:

        # Redis
        #app: cache.adapter.redis
        #default_redis_provider: redis://localhost

        # APCu (not recommended with heavy random-write workloads as memory fragmentation can cause perf issues)
        #app: cache.adapter.apcu

        # Namespaced pools use the above "app" backend by default
        #pools:
            #my.dedicated.cache: null
```

I have tried deleting the folders and re-creating them manually and also to run php bin/console cache:warmup command.
Can someone help me?

Comment: You are deploying on a Xampp server? Xampp is a development server and not suitable for production. And you are running in dev environment on purpose?

Comment: I always ran the app in symfony server during development and wanted to try to deploy it to an Appache server on my local machine before attempting to deploy it later for real to test the deployment. Would these cache errors happen if I deployed this on a different server with appache?

Answer (score 0):

First of what @stephan Vierkant said: XAMPP is only for development purposes.
I guess you get a lot of security issues running XAMPP in production.

I'm developing on linux machines. But i think on windows machines you get the same type of permission errors when your application / environment is not configured properly. I think it could be the same issue on your windows machine.

A PHP application can run in CLI mode (commands you are executing in console).
In this mode the current user is used for executing that command (`your_username`)

The other mode is via the webserver. The webserver itself running by a dedicatd user. In case of `apache2` it's often the `www-data` user.

Both, the `www-data` user and the `your_username` user do create cache entries if they not already exist.

And that's often the problem. If for example a cache entry is made by `www-data` then the permissions on that file via CLI mode (`your_username`) aren't sufficient. `your_username` has no rights to modify the file because only the owner can (`www-data`) and vice versa

On symfony.com there is a solution how to handle the permission errors:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html